# SharePoint Subscription Edition: Site Contents does not show in modern view after installing November 2022 or December 2022 Security Update

Tags: sharepoint-server

SharePoint Subscription Edition: Site Contents does not show in modern view after installing November 2022 or December 2022 Update

Ok. So, I recently migrated content databases from SP2013 to SP2016 to SP SE.

I have multiple instances of SharePoint farms running from development to predeployment and production.

For SPSE farms on build 16.0.14326.20450 (out of the box version of SPSE), the Site Contents display fine from modern or classic view.

When I set up my production environment, I made sure I had the latest SharePoint CU extracted into the Upgrade directory of the SP SE installation folder.   The production environment therefore loaded with build 16.0.15601.20226 (Nov 2022 CU).

In the production farm, the Site Contents Modern View does not display the Site Contents.   If I click on the link to "Display in Classic View," the Site Contents display again.

There may be a bug that is causing this, as I was able to replicate the issue by installing the Dec 2022 patch on my dev server which was working, but on Build 16.0.14326.20450.

Is anyone else having this issue?  Is there a fix action?

Is Microsoft going to release a bug fix patch for this issue if it is happening to others?

Answer (score 1):

The issue turns out that I installed the STS security update, but didn't install the latest WSSLOC language patch.

Both the latest STS Security Update and the latest WSSLOC Language Patch update must be installed to properly upgrade your SharePoint Subscription Edition server(s).   If there is no WSSLOC patch for the month, install the latest one from a previous month.

After installing the latest WSSLOC language patch, my site contents started appearing again in modern glory!

SharePoint Update Site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.